# Can't find correct Regular Expression

Tags: regex

sample text:

```
'Times New Roman'; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt">test </span>
<span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt">test </span>
<span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt">test </span>
<span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt">test </span>
<span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt">6. </span>
<span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt">Oktober </span>
<span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt">1997</span>
<span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:6pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt; vertical-align:super">2</span>
<span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt">),</sp
```

my Regex should match:

```
<span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:6pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt; vertical-align:super">2</span>
<span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt">)
```

my regex is now:

```
<span.*?>\d+?</span><span.*?>\)
```

Result:

```
<span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt">test </span><span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt">test </span><span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt">test </span><span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt">6. </span><span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt">Oktober </span><span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt">1997</span>***<span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:6pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt; vertical-align:super">2</span><span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:9pt; letter-spacing:0.05pt">)
```

Have tried now many but i cna't get it work

thanks for help

Comment: Use a HTML parser in whichever language you are using. Since you didn't mention this, I can't make any suggestions at this point.

Comment: not a direct answer, but a suggession: maybe use an xml parser object to store the html and then loop through each <span> tag and use regex over that. otherwise you might have to write a more complex regex. just my opinion.

Comment: ok i will load it into XmlDocument (c#), thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats hard to read exactly, but try:

`<span[^>]*>\d+?</span>.*<span[^>]*>`

By searching for characters that are not the bracket it is more clear what you are getting. I also have luck adding in .* around confusing white space areas that don't matter.

Comment: `<span[^>]*>\d*?</span><span[^>]*>\)` works, thanks for help :)